# CASE..ELSE will take extra memory for unused expression

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using `MySQL 5.7` and now I am running a SQL:

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) AS `m0`
FROM (
  SELECT (CASE WHEN ...
          ELSE CAST(app_name AS CHAR(255)) END) AS d0,
  ...
  FROM tableA
  GROUP BY (CASE WHEN ...  ELSE CAST(app_name AS CHAR(255)) END), 
  BINARY (CASE WHEN ... ELSE CAST(app_name AS CHAR(255)) END),
  ...
) AS `T_COUNT_`
```

Now the result says

`Error Code: 1038, Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size`

However, when I change the 3 `CAST(app_name AS CHAR(255))` statements to `CAST(app_name AS CHAR(25))`, it works as expected!

I know the type `CHAR(255)` will arrange 255 bytes memory and this will cost large, but `ALL` possible values have been listed in the `CASE WHEN` statement (This has been checked and confirmed many times). This means the `ELSE` in the `CASE WHEN` should not be used at all, so why I decrease the `CHAR()` there can make the SQL run normally?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *I know the type CHAR(255) will arrange 255 bytes memory* No. Depends on the charset and can be up to 1022 bytes per value.

Comment: Why you do not refer to the output column name in GROUP BY  - this is allowed. PS. What is `app_name` column datatype? why do you need to cast it to char?

Comment: hi @Akina Thanks for your reply. Actually this SQL is automatically generated by the data visualization software. I found it in the error log and quite confused with the `ELSE...` statement and unfortunately, I cannot change it...

Comment: *"but ALL possible values have been listed in the CASE WHEN statement (This has been checked and confirmed many times)."* It is nice that *you* know it (after checking, and for this moment). MySQL doesn't. It would have to run the query first to know what data might appear there. This would require it to execute the query first, thus doubling the execution time. Or it could reserve memory based on the information in the query, and your query literally tells MySQL that the else case might exist, so why would MySQL not believe that what you write in the query is true?

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks a lot for your detailed reply, I've learnt sth !   btw, ` it could reserve memory` what does the machanism `it` refers to? Could you please give some keywords so that I can search more details?